# In an organization, whose responsibility is it (or should it be) to write an Expression of Interest document?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication

I'm not sure if this is the right place to be asking this type of question, but here goes:
I am currently working as a junior software developer in the Information Systems department of a large organization. Recently,there has been a change in the management of our department and our new general manager wants me to respond to a request for expression of interest generated by another large organization requiring some software development.

He insists that since I have an MSc in Engineering with Business Management, I should be the one to do it whereas I don't even have a clue of where to begin since I haven't even encountered the term EOI (Expression of Interest) during my studies. I want to clarify to the GM that I'm not the right person for the job without coming off as irresponsible or unprofessional and making a first bad impression.

So my question is, how should I deal with this? I have tried googling for sample EOIs but they haven't been much help to me at all. Is there a specific designation/role in an organization, like someone in finance or inventory control etc. who should write such a document? Or should I take it as a challenge and start adapting?

Comment: Do not jump to conclusions. The fact that you do not know what an EOI is does not mean that you are 1) *not the right person for the job*, or 2) *coming off as irresponsible or unprofessional and making a first bad impression*. You can show effort searching Googling for the explanation, so just ask your GM what an EOI is and what they roughly expect to be in it. As for jumping to conclusions, you might even *come off as etc.* if you did **not** ask for clarification ;-)

Comment: Rather than Googling for sample EOIs, I would ask your GM to point you towards _actual_ EOIs that your company has sent out in the past. Assuming that this is normal behaviour for your company, that should be straightforward. Tell the GM that you need to ensure that your EOI is consistent with the company's past ones, since you've never done one before.

Comment: @JanDoggen Thanks a lot mate, I'll be sure to pay him a visit.

Comment: @Carson63000 The thing is, this is the first time our company is offering development services outside our company, so everything is quite new and daunting for the whole team. But considering yours and Jan Doggen's advice, consulting the GM should clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An expression of interest document is nothing more than as it's name says. When people are job hunting and they make a first contact to the hiring organization, that is said to be an expression of interest.

In your role, your GM more likely than not has selected you 1.) Because you're a developer which gives you the ability to leverage your technical experience and expertise in writing an effective EOI document; and 2.) With your business management education, he likely assumes you have the business understanding to deliver the EOI to your prospective client in a way that balances value adding business benefits with leveraging technical capabilities to show the client why your company is the best fit for the application.

How you should deal with it is accept the opportunity and adapt. More developers need to be well rounded with good business and communication skills, not just super coding skills.